# Is there a way to run a Security command for each record in a result set, without using cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, cursors

I need to Grant View Change Tracking to an AD group on every table that has change tracking enabled in a database.

I know I can do this fairly easily using a cursor, sp_executesql and the sys.change_tracking_tables system table, but I'm curious if there is a way to solve this problem without using a cursor.

I'm working in SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

Cursor example (works)

```
DECLARE @TableName AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQLCommand AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE ChangeTrackingTablesCursor CURSOR STATIC LOCAL
FOR SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS TableName
FROM sys.change_tracking_tables;

OPEN ChangeTrackingTablesCursor;
WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        FETCH ChangeTrackingTablesCursor INTO @TableName;
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
            BEGIN
                BREAK;
            END;
        SET @SQLCommand = 'GRANT VIEW CHANGE TRACKING ON OBJECT::'+@TableName+' TO [domain\groupname]';
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQLCommand, N'';

    END;
```

This works as expected, works through each Change Tracking enabled table and runs the appropriate SQL Command, but I'm trying to do this without the use of cursors and sp_executesql.

Comment: You can do this without an explicit `CURSOR` but that is just a different name. While loop, looping concatenation, they're all cursors. What is the *reason* behind not using a cursor? Do you think a while loop or something that doesn't look like a loop will be faster? Why? The slow part is executing the `GRANT`, probably, not building the string(s).

Comment: I typically like to avoid executing dynamically built SQL if I can, even in one off scripts only I will be running. I was hoping there would be a more elegant way to achieve the same result, other than that I have no reason for wanting to do this.

Comment: You’re going to have to generate dynamic SQL no matter what.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I had a feeling that would be the answer, but I figured it was worth a try.